# Swapping elements of vectors in julia

Tags: julia, swap

Let `A=[[(a,b),(c,d),(e,f),(g,h)]]`

I want to have all swapping possible using *for loop*
for example:

```
A=[[ (c,d),(a,b),(e,f),(g,h)]]
A=[[ (a,b),(e,f),(c,d),(g,h)]]
```

etc...

I can swap two elements but not the whole element as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
julia> using Combinatorics

julia> x = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> collect(permutations(x))
6-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2, 3]
 [1, 3, 2]
 [2, 1, 3]
 [2, 3, 1]
 [3, 1, 2]
 [3, 2, 1]
```